# Who can explain the reason of the behavior of this code

Tags: javascript

```js
function every(array, predicat) {
  let val;
  for (let elt of array) {
    val = predicat(elt);
  }
  if (val == true) console.log(true);
  else console.log(false);
}
every([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], n => n > 0)
```

what i want it to do is to pass all the values in the predicat() and return true if all is true and false if at least one value return false

Comment: `val` is going to be the result only of the last evaluation of `predicat()`. The loop reassigns the value on every iteration, so for example the result of `predicat()` on the fist element of the array is lost when the next iteration is made.

Comment: did you know this is built-in ([Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every))? just saying.

Comment: Thanks, but how to fix this?

Comment: yes Lawrence i do but it is an exercise, im a beginner

Comment: If you do a comparison, always use the typesafe `===` identity operator. And you should avoid comparing to `true` or `false`, unless you want to distinguish the explicit values `true`/`false` from other truthy / falsy values. But that ain't the case in this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Edit

If you want to log every time, you could try adding another control variable. You would need the current result and the final result. This would not short-circuit and it would check every value within the array. I would not recommend doing this, so consider what I originally responded with below.

```js
function every(array, predicat) {
  let finalVal = true, currentVal;
  for (let elt of array) {
    currentVal = predicat(elt);
    console.log(elt, currentVal);
    if (finalVal && !currentVal) {
      finalVal = false;
    }
  }
  return finalVal;
}

every([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], n => n > 0)
```

---

### Original response

You should be short-circuiting if the predicate fails at any point since you are checking every. There is no point to storing the result, you should just return.

```js
function every(array, predicat) {
  for (let elt of array) {
    if (!predicat(elt)) {
      return false; // short-circuit
    }
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(every([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], n => n > 0));
```

Here is a version of `some`, that checks for a truth and then breaks out. You just flip the condition and the return values.

```js
function some(array, predicat) {
  for (let elt of array) {
    if (predicat(elt)) {
      return true; // short-circuit
    }
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(some([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], n => n > 0));
```

Comment: So why i cannot  call the the console.log directly in the function? like this function every(array, predicat) {
  
  for(let elt of array) {
     if(predicat(elt) == false) console.log(false);
  }
  console.log(true);
  
}   
(every([1, 2, -3, 4, 5], n => n > 0));

Comment: @SanlexSandro why would you need to log? The method should be returning a boolean, it should not be treated like a void function.

Answer (score 3):

You're only looking at the last result, because `val` is reassigned every time you run the loop. After the loop ends, you're left with the value it was assigned last.

Instead, if you want to spot a false value, you need to spot that *within* the loop, and stop the process there. You only return true after the loop finishes, because then you know that no false values were detected.

Lastly, for the function to be truly useful within a larger program, it needs to return the result to the caller, not just log it to the console.

As was pointed out in the comments though, there's an "every" method built into the JS array object. The demo below shows both your function working correctly, and also how to do it with the built-in method (and therefore not need your custom one at all):

```js
function every(array, predicat) {
  for (let elt of array) {
    if (predicat(elt) == false) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(every([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], n => n > 0));
console.log(every([1, 2, 3, -4, 5], n => n > 0));

console.log([1, 2, 3, 4, 5].every((n) => n > 0));
console.log([1, 2, 3, -4, 5].every((n) => n > 0));
```

Comment: I would even boil it down and remove the variable `val` completely(if not needed anywhere else ofc)